# Odd function composition

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

> Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be an odd function.
>
> Is the compositon of $ \underbrace{f \circ f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{\text{$n$ times}}$ odd or even?

Do I need to prove it with separate cases for $n$ even and $n$ odd?

Comment: You don't need to consider separate cases for $n$ even and odd. Use induction to prove the result.

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is odd then $f(f(-x)) = f(-f(x))=-f(f(x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity of notation, let $f^n$ denote the $n$-fold composition of $f$ with itself, i.e.
$$ f^n := \underbrace{f\circ f \circ \dotsb \circ f}_{\text{$n$ times}}. $$
We claim that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is odd, then $f^n$ is odd for all $n$.  The proof is by induction.  As a basis for induction, note that $f^1 = f$, which is odd.

Now suppose that $f^k$ is odd.  Then for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align}
f^{k+1}(-x)
&= f(f^k(-x)) \\
&= f(-f^k(x)) &&\text{(induction hypothesis)} \\
&= -f (f^k(x)) &&\text{($f$ is odd)} \\
&= -f^{k+1}(x).
\end{align}
That is, $f^{k+1}(-x) = -f^{k+1}(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore $f^{k+1}$ is odd, which completes the induction proof.